# The skeleton is transferred to unreal engine 5 with larger bone sizes

Tags: animation

please tell me how to transfer the Unreal Engine 5 skeleton, all transformations were applied before and after attaching the skeleton to the mesh, at the very beginning of the movement, when I add a socket, the object takes on huge dimensions in the previous version. When you click on the bone the zoom icon is large, on other ue5 skeletons it is small. ps each bone is attached to the mesh individually, not the entire skeleton

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. Could you edit your post and translate all text to English? If you are not comfortable writing it yourself, feel free to use any automated online translation service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this happens because unit size in Blender and Unreal is different. You need to go to seene properties (properties tab, icon with pyramide and circles or smth) and change unit scale from 1 to 0.01. Then you need to scale skeleton and connected mesh by 100, and apply scale. That should fix it. If you have animation on this skeleton this animation will break, but that is the only way.